# Let $X = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ and let $M = \{\chi_{A} :A \subset \mathbb{R}, A ~\text{finite}\} \subset X.$

Tags: general-topology

Then, $\chi_{\mathbb{R}} \in \bar{M},$ and there is no sequence $(\chi_{A_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset M$ such that $\chi_{A_n} \to \chi_{\mathbb{R}}.$

I am having trouble with this problem since I am not sure about the topology on $X$. Even more, how can I show that $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}$ belongs to $\bar{M}$ if there is no sequence on $M$ converging for $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}.$ I imagine that this being true, then such space does not satisfy the first axiom of enumerability, but how can I solve this?

Comment: What is the topology on $M$?

Comment: @HenryW., I am sorry, induced by $X$.

Comment: and what is the topology on $X$?

Comment: I imagine that you can think $X$ as the precut space... so the topology is the product topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the topology on $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the product topology. In that case, note that if you pick a basic neighborhood $U$ of $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}$, then such neighborhood looks like $U=\prod_{r\in \mathbb{R}}U_r$ with $U_r=\mathbb{R}$ except for finitely many $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in \mathbb{R}$.

Pick $A=\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}$. Then $\chi_A\in U$. With this you have shown that $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}\in \overline{M}$. To prove that there is no sequence converging to $\chi_\mathbb{R}$ you will have to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not enumerable.

Comment: I am sorry, how can you conclude that $\chi_A \in U?$ And, how does this show that $\chi_{\mathbb{R}} \in \bar{M}?$

Comment: Remember that the definition of $x\in\overline{M}$ is that every (basic) neighborhood of $x$ contains an element in $M$. We have $\chi_A\in U$ because since $\chi_\mathbb{R}\in U$, we must have $1\in U_{r_i}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, and so the element $\chi_{A}\in U=\prod_{r\in \mathbb{R}} U_r$ (for $r\neq r_i$, $U_r=\mathbb{R}$ so it was only necessary to show that $\chi_A(r_i)=1\in U_{r_i}$.)

Comment: wow! very good! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am sorry disturb you again. Yesterday your idea was clear, and it is now, but, how can I understand the open set $U$ that you stated? I mean, it is clear what they are, but how can I and how must I see $\chi_A$ and $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}$ as elements of such neighborhoods?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Imagine each function $f\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ as a "sequence" $(a_r:=f(r))_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$. Then the basic opens of the product topology look like $U=\prod_{r\in \mathbb{R}} U_r$, where $U_r\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $U_r=\mathbb{R}$ except for finitely many $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in \mathbb{R}$ on which $U_{r_i}$ is simply an open interval. The point is that $f\in U$ if and only if $f(r)=a_r\in U_r$ for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $a_{r_i}=U_{r_i}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ (For the others you do not have to show anything since $a_r\in\mathbb{R}=U_r$).

Comment: @user26454 Thank you! it helped too much..